# PHP loop isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php

I am building a function that would receive 2 params, a string and a number.
it would basically print the first letters $n of $s.

- I need to run a loop, please don't advise other non looping methods.
- And yes, I need to keep the loop true throughout the function, it's suppose to close when the `if` is met.

For some reason the loop isn't closing, even though there's a `return` in the `if` condition that is being met when `$stringCounter` equals `$n` (=10 in this example.)

```
function printCounter($s, $n)
{
    $stringCaller = '';
    $stringCounter = strlen($stringCaller);
        while (1) {
            $stringCaller .= $s;
            if ($stringCounter == $n) {
                return $stringCaller;
            }
        }
}

printCounter('aba', '10');
```

Comment: You never change `stringCounter` inside the loop, so there's your infinite loop. While we're happy to help, if you'd done ANY kind of basic debugging yourself, like even a `echo $stringCaller, $stringCounter`, you'd have seen this.

Comment: Additionally, a `while(1)` loop is **dangerous**.  It can (and will) cause your PHP to get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: What's the expected result in your example? Why don't you use a `for`-loop or `substring`-function?

Comment: I am looking to receive only the first 10 letters from aba looping. i.e: abaabaabaa. substring would be counting the occurrence of a specific letter.

Comment: @cale_b it was either `while(1)` or `for(;;)`, I need to keep it looping until it reaches $n, but the code needs to built this way.

Comment: Even after you fix the loop issue, this will not generally return the first `$n` letters of `$s`. It will repeat all of `$s` in each iteration, so if `strlen($stringCaller)` is less than `$n`, it will add another copy of `$s` even if `$stringCaller` is fewer than `strlen($s)` characters away from `$n`. So `printCounter('aba', '10');` will actually return 12 characters.

Comment: @MarcB -im not following, where would you change `stringCounter` to? In the loop it didn't work either. This function works with `substring`, but for some reason it doesn't work with `strlen`

Comment: @Don'tPanic absolutely, that would be easily countered with `if ($stringCounter == $n/2)`

Comment: `$x = ''; $y = strlen($x)`. you basically have that. you check for the length of an EMPTY string, so `$stringCounter` is set to `0`. since you never change it again, it **STAYS** `0`, and `$y == $n` will NEVER succeed.

Comment: Since you have a potentially infinite loop, it will be safer to use inequality operators in case you overshoot your exit condition.

Comment: @MarcB Why aren't you providing an answer?

Comment: @MarcB So i'm guessing "Big chief, no caca"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my oppinion, TS is searching next approach:

```
function printCounter($s, $n)
{
    $result = '';
    $str_lenght = strlen($s);
    if(!$str_lenght) {
        return $result;
    }
    while (true) {
        $result .= $s;
        $result_lenght = strlen($result);
        if($result_lenght/$str_lenght >= $n) {
            return $result_lenght;
        }
    }
}

echo printCounter('aba', '10');
exit;
```

Comment: Excellencio! But since I want to `return $str_length` it only counts one 'aba', hence returning 3, it's supposed to strlen from all $n so it would return 30...

Comment: I've changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should imove the calc of  $stringCounter inside the loop otherwise this never change

```
    $stringCaller = '';

    while (1) {
        $stringCounter = strlen($stringCaller);
        $stringCaller .= $s;
        if ($stringCounter >= $n) {
            return $stringCaller;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed it and it's still not working, can you please edit your answer to show the full scope of the function and the function call?

Comment: `$stringCounter == $n` can only become true if `$n` is a multiple of `strlen($s)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix *part* of the issue by updating `$stringCounter` inside the loop.

```
function printCounter($s, $n)
{
    $stringCaller = '';
    while (1) {
        $stringCaller .= $s;
        $stringCounter = strlen($stringCaller); // check strlen after each addition of $s
        if ($stringCounter == $n) {
            return $stringCaller;
        }
    }
}
```

However, even after you fix that issue, there will still be cases where your loop will never exit (such as the example in your question) because `$stringCounter` can only *equal* `$n` if `$n` is a multiple of `strlen($s)`.

For the example `printCounter('aba', '10');`

```
Iteration   $stringCounter    ($stringCounter == $n)
    1             3                   false
    2             6                   false
    3             9                   false
    4             12                  false
```

Obviously `$stringCounter` will only get farther away from `$n` from that point.

So to ensure that the function will exit, check for inequality instead with:

```
if ($stringCounter >= $n) {
```

If you need the function to return *exactly* `$n` characters, the function will need to be a little more complex and take a substring of `$s` to make up the remaining characters when `$stringCounter + strlen($s)` will be greater than `$n`, or return an `$n` character substring of your result like this:

```
function printCounter($s, $n)
{
    $result = '';
    while (1) {
        $result .= $s;
        if (strlen($result) >= $n) {
            return substr($result, 0, $n);
        }
    }
}
```